# Possible to replicate this in R?

Tags: r

For this question, i have given just one **CaseNo** as an example. In my df, i have millions.

Essentially what i want if the submission time is same for case no, the first row should equal one and all the other rows should equal 0 for that submission time, then for the submission time that is different, it should be 2 and so on.

df

```
CaseNo<-c(1834096,1834096,1834096,1834096,1834096,1834096,1834096,1834096,1834096,1834096,1834096)
SubmissionTime<-c("2019-12-06  2:06:59 PM","2019-12-06  2:06:59 PM","2020-05-08  2:18:54 PM","2020-05-08  2:18:54 PM","2020-05-08  2:18:54 PM","2020-05-08  2:18:54 PM","2020-05-08  2:18:54 PM","2020-05-12  7:25:03 PM","2020-05-12  7:25:03 PM","2020-05-12  7:25:03 PM","2020-05-12  7:25:03 PM")
```

What i want:

```
CaseNo<-c(1834096,1834096,1834096,1834096,1834096,1834096,1834096,1834096,1834096,1834096,1834096)
SubmissionTime<-c("2019-12-06  2:06:59 PM","2019-12-06  2:06:59 PM","2020-05-08  2:18:54 PM","2020-05-08  2:18:54 PM","2020-05-08  2:18:54 PM","2020-05-08  2:18:54 PM","2020-05-08  2:18:54 PM","2020-05-12  7:25:03 PM","2020-05-12  7:25:03 PM","2020-05-12  7:25:03 PM","2020-05-12  7:25:03 PM")
Rank<-c(1,0,2,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0)
```

For every new case, it should start from 1.

Also, i have already arranged the df such that it goes from the oldest submissiontime to the most recent

I was thinking a combination of dense_rank and/or rank using dplyr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a function to perform this operation. This function does assume the data is already ordered, as you mentioned this in your original question. The `na.omit` bit is because you get an `NA` when operating on the first value in the vector.

Since the operations are wrapped in a function, it may be helpful to examine each line step-by-step outside the function.

```
make_rank <- function(x){
  # compare current value to previous value, take cumulative sum
  x_1 <- cumsum(c(1, na.omit(x != lag(x))))
  # compare again, replacing with 0 where values match
  c(1, na.omit(ifelse(x_1 != lag(x_1), x_1, 0)))
}

make_rank(SubmissionTime)
# [1] 1 0 2 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, both answers sufficed but i was able to follow the explanation on this one.

Comment: I just encountered a scenario in my df where the submissiontime for two cases are same.  Do you know how to take that into consideration?

Comment: So i checked your solution and it doesn't go back to one when the a new caseno starts. any help is appreciated

Comment: Is `case` a grouping variable? if so, you should treat it as such, using a function like `by` or using `group_by` and `mutate` from __`dplyr`__

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data has been sorted by both `CaseNo` and `SubmissintTime`, here is a base R option using `ave`+ `cumsum`

```
within(
  df,
  Rank <- ave(cumsum(!duplicated(df)),
    CaseNo,
    SubmissionTime,
    FUN = function(x) replace(x, seq_along(x) > 1, 0)
  )
)
```

which gives

```
    CaseNo         SubmissionTime Rank
1  1834096 2019-12-06  2:06:59 PM    1
2  1834096 2019-12-06  2:06:59 PM    0
3  1834096 2020-05-08  2:18:54 PM    2
4  1834096 2020-05-08  2:18:54 PM    0
5  1834096 2020-05-08  2:18:54 PM    0
6  1834096 2020-05-08  2:18:54 PM    0
7  1834096 2020-05-08  2:18:54 PM    0
8  1834096 2020-05-12  7:25:03 PM    3
9  1834096 2020-05-12  7:25:03 PM    0
10 1834096 2020-05-12  7:25:03 PM    0
11 1834096 2020-05-12  7:25:03 PM    0
```

**data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(CaseNo = c(1834096, 1834096, 1834096, 1834096, 
1834096, 1834096, 1834096, 1834096, 1834096, 1834096, 1834096
), SubmissionTime = c("2019-12-06  2:06:59 PM", "2019-12-06  2:06:59 PM",
"2020-05-08  2:18:54 PM", "2020-05-08  2:18:54 PM", "2020-05-08  2:18:54 PM",
"2020-05-08  2:18:54 PM", "2020-05-08  2:18:54 PM", "2020-05-12  7:25:03 PM", 
"2020-05-12  7:25:03 PM", "2020-05-12  7:25:03 PM", "2020-05-12  7:25:03 PM"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, when it says !duplicated(df), is it looking at the duplicates of the entire df or just CaseNo and Submission time?

Comment: @Piccinin1992 it looks through the entire df

Comment: So i have dozens of columns actually but for this solution, it should just check for duplicates in caseno and submissiontime

Comment: @Piccinin1992 If the criteria is just on `CaseNo` and `SubmissionTime`, you can try `!duplicated(df[c("CaseNo","SubmissionTime")]` instead